# Sharp PC401 Optoisolator Failure

Tags: opto-isolator, midi

I have a trusty 2005 Edirol UA-20 midi interface, on which MIDI in has recently stopped working. After a bit of testing it appears the Sharp PC401 optoisolator / optocoupler appears to have failed. It was stored for 7 years and was put back into service and lasted around six months. I'm curious how this would happen and if it would be common failure?

Comment: hi kolleyk, maybe you can help everyone help you by providing some more detail such as under what conditions the interface failed, lets say whether it was right after a connection/disconnection, and also which was the mode of failure of the opto if you had determined that

Comment: What exactly has failed? How do the input and the output behave, electrically?

Answer (score 1):

Any part can fail, however parts that are closer to the user and can be abused (knobs, input jacks etc.) or are stressed (off-line SMPS components, those carrying high currents, those that get hot) tend to fail far more often.

Optoisolators have an aging failure mode, however that only applies when the LED is powered and is accentuated at high temperatures. Storage is very benign.